# Number of ways to put colored balls in bins such that each color is matched with all others exactly once

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Suppose I have balls with $k$ possible colors, and $m$ of each color for a total of $mk$ balls. How many ways can I place all $mk$ balls into $k$ bins such that each color is placed in the same bin with the other colours exactly once e.g. a red ball and a blue ball are in the same bin once.

I have tried the usual inclusion-exclusion approaches for simpler problems but I keep getting caught out by the matching constraint causing some assignments to be suboptimal later on.

Comment: What does it mean for a color to match another color.

Comment: If there is a bin with $2$ red balls and $2$ blue balls does that mean red and blue matches once or does it mean red and blue match four times?

Comment: Does this that there is exactly one bin that contains both a blue ball and a red ball, for instance, though it may contain more than one of either or both?

Comment: Ah, I have edited the question to make this clearer. It simply means each pairwise color combination can appear only once in all bins.

Comment: @Jorge, that would mean it matches four times yes.

Comment: @saulspatz It does mean there is exactly one bin that contains both a blue ball and a red ball. It may not contain more than one of either since this would be a new pairing e.g. two red balls and one blue ball matches two times.

Comment: Are you sure you that is the correct problem? I get that in order for this to be possible a certain bliock design has to exist/

Comment: I don't see how you can do it at all if $m>k$.  There must be a bin with a single red ball in it.  Now we have $m-1$ red balls left to place in $k-1$ bins, so some bin gets $2$ balls.  Then there can be only red balls in that bin.  This is true for each of the colors, so each bin is monochrome, and the condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: The number of combinations may have to be zero, a concrete statement of that would be equally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $k$ colors and $m$ balls which means there is a $mk$ balls. We want to place them into $k$ bins which means each bin has $m$ balls.

Notice that if a bin is not monochrome it cannot have two balls of the same color. It follows $k\geq m$ because otherwise all bins would have to be monochrome.

Assume that there is a monochromatic bin, then that means all $m$ balls of that color are in that bin, which means that color cannot be matched to any other.

It follows that all bins contain $m$ different colors.

Notice each bin matches $\binom{m}{2}$ colors and there are $k$ bins. Since there are $\binom{k}{2}$ pairs of colors that need to be matched this means $\binom{m}{2}k = \binom{k}{2}$ or $m(m-1) = k-1$ or $k=m^2-m+1$.

Moreover if we view each color as a point and each bin as a block we must get a steiner system $S(2,m,m^2-m+1)$.

It turns out that when $m=p^a+1$ there is at least one solution because we can take a projective plane.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you expand on why there is at least one solution with a projective plane? I am unfamiliar with Steiner systems but it seems they encode these kinds of problems (combinatorics with constraints) in a general way?

Comment: I am not an expert, finding steiner systems is in general very hard and most example tend to come from algebraic structures.

Comment: Good to know - thank you for your help.

Comment: For the case where one requires exactly $l$ color pairs of each kind (instead of 1) but only one color in each bin, the new constraint would go as $\binom{m}{2}k = l\binom{k}{2}$ yes?

Comment: only one color or only one pair in each bin? If it is the second then yes.